# Variant visitor with different return types

Tags: c++, variant, boost-variant

Consider the following piece of code that uses `boost::variant` (but should apply perfectly well to `std::variant` as well).

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double> > vr 
        = std::vector<int>(5, 5);;

    // OK, no problem.
    boost::apply_visitor([](auto a) { std::cout << a[0] << "\n"; }, vr);

    // ERROR: return types must not differ.
    //boost::apply_visitor([](auto a) { return a.begin(); }, vr);
}
```

Here, we have variant that eats up standard vectors of different types (e.g., `int` and `double` in this example), and we'd like to have a visitor that returns objects of different types (in this case, iterators to the beginning of the underlying container). However, this won't compile as obviously `std::vector<int>::iterator` is not the same as `std::vector<double>::iterator`. Is there a neat way of essentially achieving this, possibly through an extra layer of indirection?

Comment: What do you want to do with the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return a different variant

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double> > vr 
        = std::vector<int>(5, 5);
    using iter_variant = boost::variant<std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<double>::iterator >;

    using value_variant = boost::variant<int, double>;

    // OK, no problem.
    boost::apply_visitor([](auto a) { std::cout << a[0] << "\n"; }, vr);

    // Also OK
    boost::apply_visitor([](auto a) -> iter_variant { return a.begin(); }, vr);

    // Also OK
    boost::apply_visitor([](auto a) -> value_variant { return a[0]; }, vr);
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13d2e5a18500ce38)

Given a generic lambda and a variant, you can get an appropriate return type.

```
template<typename Func, typename Variant>
struct visitor_result;

template<typename Func, typename ... Ts>
struct visitor_result<Func, boost::variant<Ts...>>
{
    using type = boost::variant<decltype(std::declval<Func>()(std::declval<Ts>()))...>;
};

template<typename Func, typename Variant>
using visitor_result_t = typename visitor_result<Func, Variant>::type;

template<typename Func, typename Variant>
visitor_result_t<Func, Variant> generic_visit(Func func, Variant variant)
{
    return boost::apply_visitor([&](auto a) -> visitor_result_t<Func, Variant> { return func(a); }, variant);
}
```

[See it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/682d2793f34ac7c3)

Comment: Does it require C++17 only, or soon to be C++20?

Comment: @RadosławCybulski with `boost::variant` it works with C++14, and needs C++17 only for `std::variant`

Comment: Very nice, kudos to you, sir.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Caleth's answer, this allows for any variant without duplicating the parameter list.

```
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <type_traits>

//Replace with more appropriate name
template<typename Variant, typename Lambda>
struct X_impl;
template<typename...Ts, typename Lambda>
struct X_impl<std::variant<Ts...>, Lambda>{
    using type = std::variant<std::invoke_result_t<Lambda,Ts>...>;
};
template<typename...Ts, typename Lambda>
struct X_impl<const std::variant<Ts...>, Lambda>{
    using type = std::variant<std::invoke_result_t<Lambda,const Ts>...>;
};

template<typename Variant, typename Lambda>
using X = typename X_impl<std::remove_reference_t<Variant>, Lambda>::type;


template<typename Variant, typename Lambda>
auto visit(Variant&& variant, Lambda&& lambda){
    auto wrapped_lambda = [&lambda](auto&& arg) -> X<Variant,Lambda>{ 
        using T = decltype(arg);
        return std::forward<Lambda>(lambda)(std::forward<T>(arg));
    };
    return std::visit(wrapped_lambda, std::forward<Variant>(variant));
}
int main()
{
    std::variant<std::vector<int>,const std::vector<double> > vr = std::vector<int>(5, 5);
    const std::variant<std::vector<int>,const std::vector<double> > c_vr = std::vector<int>(5, 5);
    auto& ref_vr = vr;
    auto& ref_c_vr = c_vr;

    auto visit_fnc = [](auto&& a){return a.begin();};
    visit(vr, visit_fnc);
    visit(c_vr, visit_fnc);
    visit(ref_vr, visit_fnc);
    visit(ref_c_vr, visit_fnc);
}
```

EDIT:
Oh, look like @Caleth also added general solution in the meantime.

Comment: Indeed my answer does, but you bothered with forwarding the argument etc. +1

Comment: @Caleth Yea, not sure whether I did catch everything. I did not bother with `volatile` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Use variant result type as well.
In other words:

```
boost::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double> > vr 
    = std::vector<int>(5, 5);;

boost::apply_visitor([](auto a) -> boost::variant<int, double> {
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(a)>;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<int>>) {
         int v = 0;
         for(auto q : a) v += q;
         return v;
    }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::vector<double>>) {
         double v = 0;
         for(auto q : a) v += q;
         return v;
    }
}, vr);
```

I can imagine getting this done with automatic deduction of correct variant return type, but it would take a lot of coding.

Comment: you don't need `if constexpr` here

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: you can write generic code when using `auto`. you only have to find the correct type for `v`, which is `decltype(a)::value_type` in your case

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do things differently, the iterators are different in your current case but you can bypass with that:

```
std::vector<boost::variant<int, double>> vr = std::vector<int>(5, 5);
```

It's basically the same thing.

Comment: It's really not the same thing.